# Revert Only One of Two Migrations in Sequelize-CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, migration, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

If we created 2 new migration scripts and ran

```
sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

, both migration scripts will run.

Both migrations are also reverted when we ran once the command

```
sequelize-cli db:migrate:undo
```

**Question:** Can we undo only the latest of the 2 migrations?

*Using node 13.7.0, sequelize 5.21.3, sequelize-cli 5.5.1, PostgreSQL 11.2.*

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `name` option:

```
db:migrate:undo --name 20180704124934-create-branch.js
```

Comment: This worked! Although I must admit, I'm much more used to the idea of "stepping" backwards through a migration. I guess using the name makes it more explicit to what point you're exactly migrating back to - just a bit non-standard for the frameworks I've used.

Comment: Thanks man. it works. Perhaps if sequelize cli is installed globally, a person should run the command from terminal like this `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate:undo --name db:migrate:undo --name 20180704124934-create-branch.js`

Comment: `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate :undo --name 20230406073112-create-history ` 
Unknown arguments: name, :undo `"sequelize": "^6.6.5",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",`